# ReactJS: Props not loading on initial render. Cannot use map on undefined variable

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a complex react application with many components.
The first thing is when the user logs in, I fetch the information from the database and store it in a global state, the child components then get the value using props and then I load the relevant data.

This is what a component looks like:

```
const ProfileForm12 = (props) => {
  const { profile } = props
  ...
  ...
  profile.map(x=>console.log(x))
}
export default ProfileForm12
```

Here I initially I get an error that crashes the application, because the profile is null on initial render, but on the second render, the data loads.

How can I solve this issue without using useState or useEffect because the application already uses a lot of state and using them are causing too many re-renders.

I tried putting this inside an if loop, but then the data wont load on the frontend.

UPDATE: All the suggestions below worked. I will take some time to see which one works well with my application but thank you all for your answers :)

Comment: You can conditional render the component to ensure its not NULL { profile && <ProfileForm12 profile={profile}/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can keep one null check before map method to get rid of error.

```
profile?.map(x=> console.log(x));
```

Answer (score 1):

If loading/initializing your app is a requirement for all your components, you should have some "Loading..." screen that identify the loading state, shows the loading screen, and once it's loaded. render the full app.

Protecting from `null` all over your application is not so productive.

Answer (score 1):

You want to avoid rendering the child component when the data is not set, so a ternary operator (or logical expression) should ensure that

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
...    

return (
<>
    ...
    {propsToSend && (<ChildComponent myprop={propsToSend}/>)}
</>
)
}
```

This way you guarantee that the child component only renders if the props are defined.